# Python Pandas Regex specific string

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I would like to iterate through a column of records (string directory path's) and pull out the record id which is enclosed within parentheses.  However, there are other instances where there are details enclosed within parentheses that are not record id's and need to be ignored.

Code:

```
df1['Doc ID'] = df['Folder Path'].str.extract('.*\((.*)\).*', expand=True) #this does not ignore instances with (2018-03) or (yyyy-mm)
```

I have also tried:

```
df1['Doc ID'] = df['Folder Path'].str.extract('\((?!date_format)([^()]+)\)',expand=True) #this does not ignore (Data Only)

  Folder Path                                          Doc ID
1  /report/support + admin. (256)/ Global (2018-03)    (256) # ignores: (2018-03)
2  /reports/limit/sector(139)/2017                     (139)
3  /reports/sector/region(147,189 and 132)/2018        (147, 189 and 132)
4  /reports/support.(Data Only)/Region (2558)          (2558)  #ignores(Data Only)
```

Comment: So what is your desired output?  And how are record ids distinguished from non-records?

Comment: Hi! my desired output would be in the 'Doc ID' column.  Record ID's can be distinguished from non record id's by the following: they do not include '(Data Only)' and they do not include '(yyyy-mm)' or date format- i am not sure how to combine these two arguments into into an expression that looks for data within a parentheses

Comment: Are those really the only two options? The words (Data Only) and a date format? Or is (Data Only) just a generic value meant to represent other text?

Comment: Unfortunately yes, I do not have a background in parsing via regex(do you have any suggestions of good places to learn?)-  The data that is coming in this file is really a hot mess and this is the best way of identifying the record id

Comment: (Data Only) is actually listed within the string- in about 50% of the records that contain this string there is an associated record id, in the other half, there is not-- I will run it through the script now, thanks for your help!

Comment: I just posted an updated regex that should work for you.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! this looks so much better!  I need to additional validation, but definitely significantly better than where i started!  Can you point me in a direction that would explain all of the characters in the context of how you set them up?  I have found a few sites but I do not think they do a great job of explanation.  Thanks, John

Answer (score 0):

This uses negative lookahead to filter out "Data Only" and date formats:

```
(\((?!Data Only)[^\-]+\))
```

***Setup***:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'Path': ['(Data Only) text (1, 2 and 3)',
    '(2013-08) foo (123)',
    '(Data Only) bar (1,2,3,4,5 and 6)']}
)

                                Path
0      (Data Only) text (1, 2 and 3)
1                (2013-08) foo (123)
2  (Data Only) bar (1,2,3,4,5 and 6)
```

Using `str.extract`:

```
df.Path.str.extract(r'(\((?!Data Only)[^\-]+\))', expand=True)

                   0
0      (1, 2, and 3)
1              (123)
2  (1,2,3,4,5 and 6)
```